# Entity Framework connection string required in all connected applications

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, nuget, connection-string

I'm building a system of multiple applications for a car rental agency. All should connect to the same database. There will be web application (ASP.NET), a Universal Windows Application (WPF) and a Xamarin application for inspectors in the parking lot.

I decided to start with a class library project and use Entity Framework (Code First) to create the database, and perform data validation, then publish it as a NuGet Package on an internal NuGet server, then install it in all three Applications to perform CRUD operations.

In my code, I have the connection string set in the `App.config` file of the class library project.

```
<connectionStrings><add name="ZoomAutoModel" connectionString="DATA SOURCE=localhost:1521/pdbd; PASSWORD=dummyPassword; PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True; USER ID=dummyUserId" providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" /></connectionStrings>
```

Then I created an `EntryPoint` project to test my class library before publishing, I kept getting the following error:

```
System.ArgumentException: 'Connection string was not in a correct format'
```

I made sure that I have the library in the `EntryPoint` project's references, the only way to get it to run was to copy the connection string from the Class library project into the `EntryPoint` project.

Just for testing, I published a NuGet package and tried installing it in a completely separate solution, and I kept getting the same error till I copied the connection string to its `App.config`

Where is my mistake here? I don't want to provide the Connection string in all applications' configuration files.

I refer to the connection string in the DbContext constructor like this

```
public ZoomAutoModel() : base("ZoomAutoModel")
{
}
```

Comment: `data source=localhost; DATA SOURCE=localhost:1521/pdbd;` ??? The error complains that the connection string is wrong

Comment: The config file of a class library does not get compiled into the library dll and therefore does not follow the library to other solutions when it is referenced. If you want the connection string to follow your library, it needs to be defined somewhere else.

Comment: Hard-coding the connection string into a library is a bad idea. You *will* have to change that connection string, one way or another. The server will most likely change - most applications don't run on the same server as the database. The password will change. So will the user. In a production environment it's far more likely to use a Windows account, so even the `User ID` and `Password` keywords will change

Comment: How ideally should I set my connection string in such class library then?

Comment: It really isn't a good idea to set the connection string in the class library. Per @PanagiotisKanavos comment, eventually (possibly years down the road), that connection string will have to change. You are then going to have to update the reference in every single application that references this library (possibly with breaking changes). If you must go this route, I would suggest using a custom settings library that references a global settings file stored in a secure location on your internal network, or if all applications will run from the same machine, a location on that machine.

Comment: Mobile connections are *very* unstable too. Mobile applications rarely connect directly to a database. Typically, they use queues, message passing protocols and synchronization so they don't have to connect directly. When they do connect to a database they behave *very* differently - they're far less chatty and try to download/upload as much as possible so they won't be affected if they lose connectivity later on

Answer (score 4):

> All should connect to the same database. There will be web application (ASP.NET), a Universal Windows Application (WPF) and a Xamarin application for inspectors in the parking lot.

This is never going to work, or at least not securely nor scalable.

You need a middle man, a Web API service, to which all applications send their requests, with a separate authentication mechanism separate from SQL Server's authentication (which only your API will know).

If you let your (mobile) applications connect directly to your database, then so can your users, whether you trust them or not. You'll also have to expose your database to the world, and exposed it will be, including all your users, orders, revenue...

Back to the drawing board, it is.

The answer to your actual question is that an application uses only its own configuration file, not that of any of its dependencies.

Comment: Then there's the connectivity issue. Mobile connections are by definition unstable, even over WiFi. My own home WiFi is unstable lately. Database protocols were built assuming stable connections to a server or at least, semi-stable connections to a cloud server.